# Native-Base Component Picker issue

Tags: android, react-native, expo, native-base

The app is crashing while i Load this component in the view. It used to working before.

```
import {Picker, View} from 'native-base';

<View style={{flex:1}}>
 <Picker mode="dropdown">
        <Picker.Item label="Select" value={0} />
        <Picker.Item label="Veg" value={0} />
        <Picker.Item label="Non-Veg" value={0} />
 </Picker>
</View>
```

[image: Screenshot for the error]

Answer (score 0):

it seems like native base picker has a dependency for `@react-native-community/picker`

try to install it via

```html
npm install @react-native-community/picker
npx pod-install
```

once installed it will fix the issue for you

Comment: @ShreyashKhole did u update native base to v2.13.15